# Transform property name for JSON of current bitcoin market data

Tags: azure-logic-apps

*UPDATE* - *I've amended the original question so that I'm now supplying code that can be used to easily set up a test Azure Logic App in Azure and repeat my scenario.*

I have an Azure Logic App to retrieve Crypto market data from a public API and convert it to a CSV table.

I'm performing an API request by using an HTTP action in the workflow. The action does a GET of `https://api.wazirx.com/api/v2/trades?market=btcusdt`. This results in a response with the following structure:

```
[{"id":239067645,"market":"btcusdt","price":"61999.0","volume":"0.00005","funds":"3.09995","created_at":"2021-10-25T04:00:38Z","side":null},  {"id":239065383,"market":"btcusdt","price":"61966.0","volume":"0.00021","funds":"13.01286","created_at":"2021-10-25T03:57:25Z","side":null}]
```

I want to transform the property name of one of the properties from the API response (`"market"`) to a custom property name (`"pair"`), so that I get the following as the input into the 'Create CSV table' action of my Azure Logic App:

```
[{"id":239067645,"pair":"btcusdt","price":"61999.0","volume":"0.00005","funds":"3.09995","created_at":"2021-10-25T04:00:38Z","side":null},{"id":239065383,"pair":"btcusdt","price":"61966.0","volume":"0.00021","funds":"13.01286","created_at":"2021-10-25T03:57:25Z","side":null}]
```

I'm currently using the following workflow and source code. The source code can be directly used to create the Logic App workflow in Azure using the 'consumption' SKU for an Azure Logic App. The workflow is failing at the 'Create CSV table step' as it's getting null from the body of the 'For each'.

How can I adapt my workflow code so that the input into the 'Create CSV table' action is the desired input?

[image]

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Create_CSV_table": {
                "inputs": {
                    "format": "CSV",
                    "from": "@body('For_each')"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_each": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Table"
            },
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Compose": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "pair": "@items('For_each')?['market']"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "Compose"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('Parse_JSON')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "HTTP": {
                "inputs": {
                    "method": "GET",
                    "uri": "https://api.wazirx.com/api/v2/trades?market=btcusdt"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Http"
            },
            "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@body('HTTP')",
                    "schema": {
                        "items": {
                            "properties": {
                                "created_at": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "funds": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "id": {
                                    "type": "integer"
                                },
                                "market": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "price": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "side": {},
                                "volume": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            },
                            "required": [
                                "id",
                                "market",
                                "price",
                                "volume",
                                "funds",
                                "created_at",
                                "side"
                            ],
                            "type": "object"
                        },
                        "type": "array"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "HTTP": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ParseJson"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Logic App expression to handle JSON array object as string and then transfer it back to JSON array.

More information for logic app expression: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference

Please try this logic app code:

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": "@json(replace(string(body('HTTP')),'\"market\"','\"pair\"'))",
                "runAfter": {
                    "HTTP": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Create_CSV_table": {
                "inputs": {
                    "format": "CSV",
                    "from": "@outputs('Compose')"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Table"
            },
            "HTTP": {
                "inputs": {
                    "method": "GET",
                    "uri": "https://api.wazirx.com/api/v2/trades?market=btcusdt"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Http"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @mostawk - a simple and maintainable way to achieve the result

Comment: where do I find the reference to `@outputs` and `@json`? Do you know what these are called? Are they functions that are available in an Azure Logic Apps expression? There's no reference to `@json` here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#date-and-time-functions

Answer (score 1):

This is how I achieved your requirement

Since `Create CSV table` only takes Array values as input. I have initialized an array variable and Added `Append to array variable` connector instead of compose then passing the same to `Create CSV table`.

Here are the logic app screenshots

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Here is the workflow**

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Create_CSV_table": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "format": "CSV",
                            "from": "@variables('Array')"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "Table"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@variables('Array')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_each_2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "For_each_2": {
                "actions": {
                    "Append_to_array_variable": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "Array",
                            "value": {
                                "created_at": "@items('For_each_2')['created_at']",
                                "funds": "@items('For_each_2')['funds']",
                                "id": "@items('For_each_2')['id']",
                                "pair": "@items('For_each_2')['market']",
                                "price": "@items('For_each_2')['price']",
                                "side": "@items('For_each_2')['side']",
                                "volume": "@items('For_each_2')['volume']"
                            }
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "AppendToArrayVariable"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('Parse_JSON')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "HTTP": {
                "inputs": {
                    "method": "GET",
                    "uri": "https://api.wazirx.com/api/v2/trades?market=btcusdt"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Http"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Array",
                            "type": "array"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@body('HTTP')",
                    "schema": {
                        "items": {
                            "properties": {
                                "created_at": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "funds": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "id": {
                                    "type": "integer"
                                },
                                "market": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "price": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "side": {},
                                "volume": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            },
                            "required": [
                                "id",
                                "market",
                                "price",
                                "volume",
                                "funds",
                                "created_at",
                                "side"
                            ],
                            "type": "object"
                        },
                        "type": "array"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "HTTP": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ParseJson"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {},
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    }
}
```